# awk to split field and place split at end of file

Tags: awk

Trying to use `awk` to split `$1` on the `-` and print the 4th value in the last column of `file` with an empty tab in between. The below does execute but just prints `file` as is. Thank you :).

**file**  `tab-delimited`

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 Long Header4    Header5 Header6
00-0000-12345-xxx-yy_0  /path/to/file   aaaaa   1111
00-0008-67899-yyy-zz_8  /path/to/file   aaaaa   1111
```

**desired**  `tab-delimited`

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 Long Header4    Header5 Header6
00-0000-12345-xxx-yy_0  /path/to/file   aaaaa   1111        xxx
00-0008-67899-yyy-zz_8  /path/to/file   aaaaa   1111        yyy
```

**awk**

```
awk 'NR > 1; {split($1,a,"-"); a[4]} {a[4]=$NF","a[4]}1' OFS="\t" file
```

Comment: The number of columns in your record `$NF` are based on the current row, not the header. Also the assignment goes like `<thing to which we are assigning value>=<value>` so your `a[4]=$NF` is backwards, and if that is fixed it will overwrite your `1111`. Instead I think you were aiming at something like `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}NR==1;NR>1{split($1,a,"-");print $0,a[4]}'`. However, @Freddy's answer below is a much simpler way of pulling this off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-` as input field separator:

```
awk -F'-' 'NR==1{print; next} {print $0"\t"$4}' file
```

Print the first line unmodified and print the line, a tab character and the fourth field otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk:

```
awk -F ' +|-' 'NR==1{print}; NR>1{print $0 "\t" $4}' file
```

Output:

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 Long Header4    Header5 Header6
00-0000-12345-xxx-yy_0  /path/to/file   aaaaa   1111    xxx
00-0008-67899-yyy-zz_8  /path/to/file   aaaaa   1111    yyy
```

Comment: That'd work in any awk, nothing GNU-specific about it.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are fine and it's no big deal but here's a tweak so you don't need 2 separate `print` statements:

```
$ awk -F'-' '{print $0 (NR>1 ? "\t" $4 : "")}' file
Header1 Header2 Header3 Long Header4    Header5 Header6
00-0000-12345-xxx-yy_0  /path/to/file   aaaaa   1111    xxx
00-0008-67899-yyy-zz_8  /path/to/file   aaaaa   1111    yyy
```